# resolveNativePath motorola device issue

Tags: android, ionic-framework, ionic3, filepath

My requirement is to upload the filename with special characters also. My code for android device is :

```
if (self.device.platform == 'Android') {
  let permissions = cordova.plugins.permissions;
  self.UserUtils.addPermission(permissions.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE).then((success) => {
    self.fileChooser.open().then((path: any) => {
      console.log(path);
      console.log("fileChooser successCallback");
      (window as any).FilePath.resolveNativePath(path, function (path: any) {
        let a = path.split('/');
        let fileName = a.pop();
       

       //fileName = fileName.replace(/[&\/\\#,+()$~%@£=!-'":*?<>{}]/g,'_').replace(/_{2,}/g,'_');


        let fileObj = self.fileService.getFileNameExt(fileName);
        let onlyName = fileObj.onlyName;
        let ext = fileObj.ext;
        let p = a.join().replace(/,/g, "/");
        p = p + "/";
        console.log(p, fileName);
        self.file.checkFile(p, fileName)
          .then(function (suc) {
            console.log(suc,"suc");
            self.file.readAsBinaryString(p, fileName)
              .then(function (success: any) {
                console.log("readAsBinaryString sucess");
                self._zone.run(() => {
                  self.attachments[id] = {
                    docName: onlyName,
                    docType: ext,
                    scoreDocument: btoa(success),
                    // scoreDocument: success,
                    delete: true
                  };
                });
                console.log("Attachment::",self.attachments[id]);
              }).catch(function (error) {
                console.log("readAsBinaryString fail", error);
              });
          }).catch(function (err) {
            console.log("checkFile false");
            console.log(err);
            console.log(JSON.stringify(err));
          });
      }, self.failureCallback);
    }).catch(e => console.log(e));
  }, (err) => {
    console.log(err);
  })
}
```

I have tried the below scenarios:
a. Removed file check File function. With this there is no need to replace special characters but it does not work with Motorola devices. Resolve Native Path gives error.
b. If i replace special characters then check File function resolves to false.

Comment: Dear Aman , Thanks for posting in stack over flow, it would be great which line number error or screenshot of error your trying to face , Thanks

Comment: Dear @DilipD, the line where we have called readAsBinaryString() function is called